# **Unknown column 'timeStamp' in 'field list'**

Tags: mysql, sql, database

*I'm getting this error, I am new to sql I don't get any solution regarding my problem, I would really Appreciate if someone can help get me rid of this error*

```
SELECT job.jobStatusId, 
       job.customerId,
       mazdoor.mazdoorName,
       mazdoor.picture , 
       job.mazdoorId, 
       job.workingHistoryId, 
       service.serviceName, 
       service.price , 
       contractor.cnic , 
       contractor.contractorId, 
       contractor.contractorName , 
       SUM(CONCAT(Extract(HOUR From timeStamp) ,'.', Extract(MINUTE From timeStamp))*service.price*0.05 ) AS GRANDTOTAL , 
       Date(job.timesStamp) AS Date 
FROM job  
INNER JOIN mazdoor ON mazdoor.mazdoorId = job.mazdoorId 
INNER JOIN service ON service.serviceId = job.serviceId 
INNER JOIN contractor ON mazdoor.contractorId = contractor.contractorId  
WHERE job.jobStatusId = '3' 
  AND mazdoor.jobsCompleted>=1  
  AND  mazdoor.contractorId = '$email' 
GROUP BY contractor.cnic
```

Comment: The server can't be wrong. If it says "no such field" then no such field in source tables. Check field names letter-by-letter.

Comment: Query seems to be fine ? @Akina

Comment: How can you pull 12 fields and GROUP BY on only one?

Answer (score 0):

--The column was misspelled

```
SELECT job.jobStatusId, 
       job.customerId,
       mazdoor.mazdoorName,
       mazdoor.picture , 
       job.mazdoorId, 
       job.workingHistoryId, 
       service.serviceName, 
       service.price , 
       contractor.cnic , 
       contractor.contractorId, 
       contractor.contractorName , 
       SUM(CONCAT(Extract(HOUR From timeStamp) ,'.', Extract(MINUTE From timeStamp))*service.price*0.05 ) AS GRANDTOTAL , 
       Date(job.timeStamp) AS Date --< column name was wrong. 
FROM job  
INNER JOIN mazdoor ON mazdoor.mazdoorId = job.mazdoorId 
INNER JOIN service ON service.serviceId = job.serviceId 
INNER JOIN contractor ON mazdoor.contractorId = contractor.contractorId  
WHERE job.jobStatusId = '3' 
  AND mazdoor.jobsCompleted>=1  
  AND  mazdoor.contractorId = '$email' 
GROUP BY  job.jobStatusId, 
       job.customerId,
       mazdoor.mazdoorName,
       mazdoor.picture , 
       job.mazdoorId, 
       job.workingHistoryId, 
       service.serviceName, 
       service.price , 
       contractor.cnic , 
       contractor.contractorId, 
       contractor.contractorName ,
       Date(job.timeStamp)
`
-- and the non-aggregate fields has to be group by
```